# Finding Vigenère cipher key(s)

Tags: cryptanalysis, vigenere

How can we find the key used with a Vigenère  cipher in small number of steps?

If we have text like:

```
Peit Wokm! Mhfa fepatgb ets bvvrvxmea ebte bae twkd qiqi
```

and we have key information like `Key =  ‘ ? a ? i ’`, then how I can understand this and solve this to make the complete key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been given the key length, plus half the characters in the key text. By the look of things, the ciphertext even contains word spaces and punctuation, which will help a lot.

Start by decrypting the text using the characters you already know:

```
> Peit Wokm! Mhfa fepatgb ets bvvrvxmea ebte bae twkd qiqi
  .a.i .a.i  .a.i .a.i.a. i.a .i.a.i.a. i.a. i.a .i.a .i.a
< .e.l .o.e! .h.s .e.s.g. w.s .n.r.p.e. w.t. t.e .o.d .a.i
```

Assuming the plaintext is English, it seems likely that the first character of the key is `t`, since this would decrypt the 5th and 8th words to `was` and `the`. Let's see how that changes things:

```
> Peit Wokm! Mhfa fepatgb ets bvvrvxmea ebte bae twkd qiqi
  ta.i ta.i  ta.i ta.ita. ita .ita.ita. ita. ita .ita .ita
< We.l Do.e! Th.s me.sag. was .ncr.pte. wit. the .ord .axi
```

Actually, you can stop here. It's already obvious what the message says.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still do we need to make idea like first letter is `t` or there is any logic or procedure behind it ?

Comment: @ARG If you don't have any information about the key or its length, then the standard attack on Vigenère ciphers is as follows: (1) use [Kasiski's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination) to determine the key length, then (2) split the ciphertext into sets of characters that are all shifted by the same key character (in this example, the first set would be `P, W, M, f, t, t, v, m, b, a, k, q`), and finally (3) use [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) to figure out the Caesar shift of each set (thus discovering each letter of the key).

Comment: How P, W, M, f, t, t, v, m, b, a, k, q ? isn't it like 'P,W,M,F,E,B,E,B,T,Q' or its not the first letters of the words ? you are doing some other thing to make key character

Comment: @ARG No, no. Ignore all the spaces and punctuation when encrypting and decrypting. The second set is `e, o, h, e, g, s, r, e, t, e, d, q` — these are the letters that have an `a` underneath them in the example above.